# NO/YES iOS like button with modal on YES

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, button, modal-dialog, bootstrap-switch

How can I create iOS like sliding button with NO/YES state, which opens modal window when it's on YES?

Can this be done with bootstrap?

I found this code that I could use but I need someone to edit JS code so that modal only is shown on button YES state.

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0owp23ug/)**

HTML

```
<div>
  Change status:
  <input type="checkbox" class="switch" id="myswitch" checked />
</div>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="showModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        This is the modal
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

JS

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
   $("#myswitch").bootstrapSwitch();

   $('#myswitch').on('switchChange.bootstrapSwitch', function(e, data) {
     $('#showModal').modal('show');
   });
 });
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate us your effort showing the necessary part of the code?

Comment: Not right now since I'm on my mobile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it can be done with bootstrap,

Add data attributes `data-off-text="No" data-on-text="Yes"` to replace `OFF` and `ON`

```
<div>
  Change status:
  <input type="checkbox" class="switch" id="myswitch" checked="" data-off-text="No" data-on-text="Yes"/>
</div>
```

All you need is to check the `bootstrap switch` state if `true` and show the modal

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#myswitch").bootstrapSwitch();

    $('#myswitch').on('switchChange.bootstrapSwitch', function(event, state) {
        if (state == true) {
            $('#showModal').modal('show');
        }
    });
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0owp23ug/7/)

SideNote: Optionally, the `state` of bootstrap swtich reset to `false` when modal closed with boostrap modal event listener,
so no need to click on switch to reset it's state.

```
    $('#showModal').on('hide.bs.modal', function() {
        $("#myswitch").bootstrapSwitch('state', false, true);
    });
```

[Fiddle With Modal Event Listener](http://jsfiddle.net/0owp23ug/8/)

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is exactly what I need.